# Naming a pattern changes outcome in StringCases[]

Tags: string-manipulation

```
s = "1 2 ";
StringCases[s, (n : NumberString ~~ " ") .. ]
StringCases[s, (NumberString ~~ " ") .. ]
```

yields

```
{"1 ", "2 "}
{"1 2 "}
```

Why?

Comment: If you parenthesize, as in `(n : NumberString)`, what happens?

Comment: You may want to analyze the output of **StringPattern`PatternConvert[pattern]** in both cases

Comment: what would `n` be set to if the second case was the result?

Comment: By naming the number string `n` in the first situation you are specifying that only patterns of the form `(n~~" ")..` will match, where the repeating element must contain the same number `n`. Since 2!=1 you don't match any further. In the second case you allow any number digit in the repeated part of the pattern. Try matching `1 1 `.

Comment: @N.J.Evans That sounds like an answer to me

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Patterns get confusing quickly. If you name a pattern you're imposing more restrictions on that pattern that are sometimes difficult to follow. Using your example,

```
s = "1 2 ";
StringCases[s, (n : NumberString ~~ " ") .. ]
StringCases[s, (NumberString ~~ " ") .. ]
```

In the first case you're telling string cases to match `n`, where n must be a number string and to continue the pattern for any match with the parenthetical statement repeated. In the repeated suffix n must always be the same number!

In the second case you're specifying that any repeated pattern of NumberString+Whitespace should match. Since you haven't named the number string, the pattern still applies generally to any number.

Trying

```
 s = "1 1 1 2 2";
 StringCases[s, (n : NumberString ~~ " ") .. ]
 StringCases[s, (NumberString ~~ " ") .. ]
```

Will give:

```
{1 1 1 , 2 2 }
{1 1 1 2 2 }
```

Which shows that the first pattern works any time the integer following the white space is the same as the n that triggered the match.

Comment: (+1) Here is an example which demonstrates that this behavior is consistent with the usual behavior of the *Mathematica*'s pattern-matcher: `{MatchQ[{1, 1, 2}, {x_Integer ..}], MatchQ[{1, 1, 2}, {_Integer ..}]}`.

Comment: And this is the correct answer. I'm not sure why I did not see this because in normal patterns like `{x_Integer..}` it is completely clear and I use it all of the time.